# Flash Action Script: how to have a common delay(ms) for a frame by frame animation in the timeline using AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I am working with Action Script 3 for the first time. I am trying to animation few frames, i want to give a delay to each frame. I am currently using the below script on each frame for 20-frames in total.

```
stop();
setTimeout(function() { nextFrame(); }, 100);
```

here if i want to increase/decrease the delay i have to change the value in every single frame. I am pretty sure i am not doing the smart way. please help me out. Thanks in Advance Experts.

Comment: Did my solution below help?

Answer (score 1):

While the easiest solution would be to just adjust your frame rate to 10fps (the equivalent of 100ms between slides), there are reasons that may not be appropriate (animations inside the timeline etc).

Perhaps a `Timer` would be better.

Something like this:

```
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;

//create a timer
var timer:Timer = new Timer(100); //fire every 100ms

//listen for it's tick, and run the timerTick function every interval
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerTick);

//start the timer
timer.start();


function timerTick(e:Event):void {
    //if the next frame is the last frame, stop the timer
    if(this.currentFrame == this.totalFrames - 1){
        timer.stop();
    }

    //go to the next frame
    nextFrame();
}
```

On your individual frames, you can tweak the timer's delay (how long before ticking) or stop the timer all together.   This can be helpful if you wanted to say pause for user interaction at some point, or make the delay longer/shorter for certain frames.

```
timer.delay = 200;
```

or

```
timer.stop();
```